# How can I use CSS code on hover an object (move to the right and on hover to right, move it to the left)?

Tags: css

I need help on CSS when hover an object, it moves to the right and on hover to right, and when hover again, moves it to the left.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to do some research and try to implement some code. If you are then still stuck please put your code into your question and describe what is and isn't working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

if want 2 effect into one object i think you must use js, i dont think you can use an hover with 2 effect in the same object.

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100vh;
}
.move {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: green;
   transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

.move:hover {
   transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="move"></div>
```